# IIS UploadReadAheadSize value meaning

Tags: iis-7, umbraco, umbraco7

Hi I'm encountering an error saying Request is too large in my Umbraco CMS when uploading large file. Now I've read that I need to modify the Configuration Editor in IIS specifically the `UploadReadAheadSize` now upon opening the configuration it's value is set to `41265` may I know if this is in KB? or MB? Basically I want to be able to upload file bigger than 20mb. What value should I place here?

Comment: Is your issue solved?

If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members.

If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it.

We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue.

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal I haven't tried these suggestion yet as I have not work on it these past few days. Will definitely accept an answer and give you feedback if one of these answer works

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/serverruntime says

The maxRequestEntityAllowed and uploadReadAheadSize attributes respectively configure limits for the maximum **number of bytes** allowed in the entity body of a request and the **number of bytes** a Web server will read into a buffer and pass to an ISAPI extension.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: And also, this has nothing to do with Umbraco, so no need to use those tags ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To increase the file upload limit in iis you could use the requestFiltering feature:

1)Open iis manager, select your site.

2)Select Requests Filtering and open it by double-clicking the icon. The Request Filtering pane displays.

[image]

3)From the Actions pane on the right-hand side of the screen click the Edit Feature Settings... link. The Edit Request Filtering Settings window displays.

4)In the Request Limits section, enter the appropriate Maximum allowed content length (Bytes) and then click the OK button.

[image]

5)Restart IIS.